# Display user friendly Devise nested validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form on my Devise sign-up page.  I have a Company model linked to the User via a Role model.

See here for a related post: [How do I update a nested resource without passing the data via a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039893/how-do-i-update-a-nested-resource-without-passing-the-data-via-a-form)

I can set my validations etc. and they work great but when the error message is displayed for the nested resource it gets ugly - literally:

For example if I submit a blank form I get:

```
>     Email can't be blank
>     Password can't be blank
>     Roles company name can't be blank
>     Roles company address1 can't be blank
```

The first two are non-nested form elements and the last two are descriptive but hardly User friendly.  They should be 'Company Name' and 'Company Address' can;t be blank etc.

Can I change this without some huge convoluted chunk of code?

**UPDATE**

I may have to manually override the Devise error message helper:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

I wanted to clean up the formatting anyway.

**UPDATE 2**

I did some digging and I found this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

From what I gather should I not be able to to this in my en.yml:

```
en:
    activerecord:
        attributes:
            user/role/company:
                address1: "First Name"
                name: "Company Name"
```

I tried that but no luck so far.

**UPDATE 3**

The more I dig the more I find.  This may be the best solution:

https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg

This gem (although not maintained for many years) lets you remove the model attribute entirely.  I may go this route and just define custom error messages anyway.

Comment: You have manually add message in validates :add_user_specific message in your nested model.

Comment: I added: validates :address1, :presence => { :message => "Address Required" } and now I get: "Roles company address1 Address Required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"custom-err-msg"[Custom error Gem](https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg) does not really depend on rails version. So it will best to use or otherwise you have override full_messages method by yourself or you have add nested model validation in parent model itself.

Comment: I agree - it's the best way to go and easy to customize etc.